# Expanding and collpasing specific rows in angular ui grid tree

Tags: treeview, angular-ui-grid

How can we use expandRow for expanding a particular row in angular ui grid tree view. Can I get an example of this?

Comment: can we have the configuration of your grid ?

Comment: Read [UI-Grid Documentation](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/215_treeView), a working example is provided.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following link for tree expansion and addition of nodes.You can add a ng-click controller to this functionality which will make this tree visible(hide it initially with ng-hide).

https://angular-ui-tree.github.io/angular-ui-tree/#/basic-example